# What is the default concurrency of CnosDB client?

Tags: database, cnosdb

I'm starting a connection to a CnosDB cluster but would like to increase the concurrency of the client. Having found this parameter from the [doc](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/tools/cli.html):

> -t --target-partitions      Optional; the number of slices to execute the query, increasing which can increase concurrency. Not specified by default.

If not specified, what is the default concurrency level? 1 or other number?

Answer (score 2):

When the client starts without target partions, it checks the number of cpu cores on the computer and sets it to this value.We'll update the document later

Comment: thank u, dude! It's been bothering me for a long time.

Comment: physical cores? or virtual cores?